# Read all data from a table of 10k rows in a single request

Tags: pact

Could there be problems in reading all the data of a 10k rows table in a single request?

It would be a read only request.

I would like to do it because I want to perform some queries on the array, and from the documentation I can’t find a way to do it directly with **Pact**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there shouldn't be. Read only queries are "free" atm.
You can do it in two ways

1. Do a `select` query which will always evaluate true
2. Get all the keys (i.e. unique ids in the table) via `(keys your-table-name)` and then have a separate method which returns data for a list of ids.

But do consider using `select` statements to help filter out your data during the query as this could be easier than you doing it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Pact will check arrays like any other property, but you should ask yourself the question - do you need to test all 10k records or just a representative sample of them (the answer should in most cases be the latter).

You should also consider:

1. Do you need to exact match? (if so, the consumer and provider must have exactly the same data - not recommended)
2. Can you use matchers to check the shape of the items in the array